# How to test Android Facebook mobile install ads

Tags: android, facebook, mobile, installation, ads

Can we test whether the Facebook mobile install ads for my android apps that we setup is really works ? 
Is there any sandbox to test it ?

If after setting up we got 1000 clicks and no install, could it be something wrong about our setting, and how can we determine what's wrong ?

Comment: Do you have the Facebook SDK integrated into your app? And are any of your users using the Facebook integration, or are you calling Settings.publishInstallAsync somewhere?

Comment: Yes I have used the Facebook SDK.
and I call the Settings.publishInstallAsync in onResume method of all activities as suggested.
I don't understand what you meant by "are any of your users using the Facebook integration", can you explain it more ?

Comment: If you're calling publishInstallAsync directly, then that's all you need to do. Be sure to upgrade to version 3.0.1 of the SDK, there were some bug fixes around the publishInstall code. As for "Facebook integration", I meant that if you use the other core features of the SDK (like Session, facebook connect, etc), then publishInstall is called for you automatically, but if you're not, then you need to call it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You Generated Facebook Ads Id From the Facebook Audience Network.So For that You are using an Facebook Account to generate Ids for your Ads.You need to Login that Facebook Account into your mobile Facebook Application,then test the mobile Application in your mobile.You will see Facebook Ads in your Application.

This will be working.